# I want to have collections of variables and select which set I choose from, I tried nested variable assignment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a module for which I need to pass a set of values via `variables.tf`, currently, the variables are grouped by the suffix on the name, i.e. `-dev` or `-stg`, etc

The module itself doesn't care which set it gets, but I must decide somewhere, so I pass the suffix at terraform invocation time or in a .tfvars file.

How can I get the following code to work, or how else should I do it?

```
module "alb" {
...
# these work but is ugly and inflexible
# connect_alb_client_id         = var.connect_alb_client_id-dev
# connect_alb_client_id         = var.connect_alb_client_id-stg

# this doesn't work
  connect_alb_client_id         = "${var.connect_alb_client_id}${var.suffix}"
# and neither does this
  connect_alb_client_id         = "${var.connect_alb_client_id${var.suffix}}"
# so what is the correct syntax or alternative way of doing it
...
}

variable "suffix"
  type = string
  default = "-dev"
# default = "-stg"
}

variable "connect_alb_client_id-dev" {
  type = string
  default = "abcdef"
}

variable "connect_alb_client_id-stg {
  type = string
  default = "ghijkl"
}
```

Comment: I don't know terraform but what about `var["connect_alb_client_id-${var.suffix}"]`  With javascript you can use `x.y` or `x["y"]` so it might work here.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 2):

Your `connect_alb_client_id` should be a `map` with keys of `dev`, `stg` and so on:

```
variable "connect_alb_client_id" {
  default = { 
    dev = "abcdef"
    stg = "ghijkl" 
  }
}
```

then:

```
module "alb" {

 connect_alb_client_id         = var.connect_alb_client[var.suffix]

}
```